# Message not sent through XMPP

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmpp, xmppframework

I am using XMPP in my app. My messages are not being sent whenever I attempt to send a message to any specific ID (for example 'test.codemen@gmail.com' in my code).
My code is given below. Thanks in advance.

```
- (IBAction)sendMsg:(id)sender 
{
    NSXMLElement *body = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"body"];
    [body setStringValue:msgField.text];

    NSXMLElement *message = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"message"];
    [message addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"chat"];
    [message addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:@"test.codemen@gmail.com"];
    [message addChild:body];

    iPhoneXMPPAppDelegate *share = [iPhoneXMPPAppDelegate sharedInstance];
    [[share xmppStream] sendElement:message];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your code looks fine to me.
Google Talk routes messages only to contacts you are subscribed to. Is the user you send the message to on your contact list?

Comment: Yes, the user is in my contact list.

Answer (score 0):

Print the xml , then see what's in the message .Maybe you are sending message to a wrong JID .